# PHP - Boost Solr Search by Date AND special Property

Tags: php, solr

i wanted to sort items (Webshop) from the solr results by "date" IF they are in a category AND boost them if they are from a Premium-Seller so that the score value is higher for these items.

```
shopitemexample {
 category = 1234
 created = 6.1.2015
 premiumseller = 0/1
 title, description...
}
```

(created is a Date, i simplified here only for the example)

but i see no effect with or without the boost function.. what is wrong with the code?

```
  $query = " categoryid:1234 OR categoryid:1234 "

  $squery = new SolrQuery ();
  $squery->setQuery ( $query );

  $squery->setParam('boost', 'recip(ms(NOW,created),3.16e-11,1,1)'); //just a test, no effect
  $squery->setParam('qf', "premiumseller^20 "); //just a test, no effect

  $squery->setStart ( "10" );
...
  $solr = new Solrhelper ();
  $solrresponse = $solr->query ( $squery );

  $solrdata = $solrresponse->getResponse ();
```

To be clear, the query itself works and a

```
$squery->addSortField ( 'created', SolrQuery::ORDER_ASC );
```

works but the results are then not based on the score so i cannot boost some items... 
Any Ideas?

And why did the 2 lines dont have an effect , i got the results in the same order "not" sorted by date... ?

I checked the docu and many answers here but ive really no idea whats wrong.